# Music player does not start when pressing Play on stereo

Tags: 7.0-nougat, bluetooth-audio, asus-zenfone-3

I have a new Asus Zenfone 3 I bought back in February. I'm having issues getting my bluetooth devices to automatically start playing when paired.

With all my previous phones, I can pair the device with bluetooth speakers (i.e. car stereo or portable speaker), press the **Play** button on the bluetooth device, and the phone would start playing music from the last app. This worked with a Samsung S2, LG G2, OnePlus One, and OnePlus Two. The process should be the same, in my experience.

On my Asus phone, I have tried with both Vanilla Music Player (F-Droid App Store) and the Google Play Music app. I have started songs, got to my car, and have it continue playing. If it stops for whatever reason (i.e. a phone call), then I have to fiddle with the phone to get music playing again.

My goal is to have my old behaviour without being forced to wipe and root it - connect to a bluetooth speaker, and use the bluetooth's controls for the music app *even if it's not currently running*.

The phone is running Android 7.0, phone model number is ASUS_Z012DC

Comment: Does the play button even work when the app is opened? Maybe the ROM doesn't have AVRCP support built at all.

Comment: @TomYan Yes, if it's the foreground app, it works. If I pause the stereo, then hit Play, it works.